# Grouping of jQuery's events

Tags: jquery

Can you group jQuery's events like with `switch();`?

Something like:

```
$(element).bind({
    blur:
    keyup: function(){ /* both do the same stuff */ }
    /* Update below */
    click: function(){ /* specific stuff */ },
    mouseenter: function() { /* more specific stuff */ }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the bind method to group jQuery events:

```
$("myItem").bind("click blur keyup", myFunction);
```

**UPDATE**

Having read a little more into the bind method since your update, it seems that since jQuery 1.4 we can do exactly what you're asking for:

```
$('#foo').bind({
  click: function() {
    // do something on click
  },
  mouseenter: function() {
    // do something on mouseenter
  }
});
```

Taken from: http://api.jquery.com/bind/#multiple-events

I notice now that it's not exactly as you're asking. What you can do is assign the same function to different events but as far as I can tell, there no way to do a direct chaining of events using this method. I tried `bind({click, blur: function(){}})` for example and a few other ways but none of them seem to work.

Comment: I was thinking more of a way, to bind some events with one function and some with their own, see update.

Comment: Ah, thanks for your effort. I'm aware of multiple event binding, was thinking to perform same task on 2 different events, while having other events do their own stuff. See that updated version of question, and ignore the `*/ Update below */` line, therefore grouping `blur` and `keyup` in one, while `click/mouseenter` has their own stuff to do.

Comment: Yeah I just got what you meant part way through answering. As far as I can see there's no way to do this type of event chaining. I've updated my answer to include that bit too. I tried a few things but none of them worked.

Comment: Well, agreed that the question is a little unclear. Anyways, thanks for the effort again, accepted. I guess @Justin's answer is the closest solution, but huh, for one line of code, pointless to write a function.

Answer (score 3):

No, but you can do this to make the code more concise:

```
function myFunction(){ /* stuff to do */ }

...

onblur: myFunction,
onkeyup: myFunction,
```

Answer (score 3):

I came across this question while searching for a similar way to do this to - i have found 
using the code below worked for me - note, this will only work if you are using jquery 1.7+

$("#someID").on("keyup click change blur", function() {

//whatever to be run goes here

});

Just wanted to add this in here in case it helps people running a more recent jquery version :)

Answer (score 2):

No but you can string them together - $().blur(process).keyup(process), and define the functionality in process separate.

Linking them in the fall-through way is not possible - although if you want to write a plug in....

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#foo").bind( "blur keyup click mouseenter", function(event) {
    switch(event.type) {
        case "blur":
        case "keyup": alert('first'); break;
        case "click": alert('click' ); break;
        case "mouseenter": alert('mouse'); break;
        default: break;
    }
});
```

You can bind the four events in the function call, then use a regular javascript switch statement on event.type to handle the different cases.

Comment: Thought about this one too, but too much useless code and not that readable. Long story short - overkill!